# How to declare variables in procedure in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

In PL/SQL I have learned that there are two ways to define procedures like below.

**Method 1**

```sql
DECLARE 
    a number;
PROCEDURE print(mynum number) IS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(mynum);
END;
```

**Method 2**

```sql
CREATE print(mynum number) IS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.print_line(mynum);
END;
```

But only in method 2, the procedure will store in DBMS as we can call it again and again. What is the difference between two different methods of creating a PLSQL procedure and how we can create and save the store procedure in DBMS which consists of declared variables?

Comment: What has this got to do with declaring variables? A procedure isn't a variable, if that's what you're suggesting. Also, Method 1 doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you posted invalid syntax, OK - I think I understand the question.

If you want the procedure to be **stored**, you have to use what you called "Method 2", e.g.

```
create or replace procedure print (mynum number) is
  a number;                      --> locally declared variable
begin
  a := mynum * mynum;
  dbms_output.put_line(mynum);
  dbms_output.put_line(a);
end;
/
```

---

The first piece of code ("Method 1") represents an anonymous PL/SQL block whose contents is "lost" at the end of your session (i.e. when you disconnect).